# Can different linear structures in a non-empty set over a given number field have same dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We know that the linear space (vector space) is a non-empty set over a number field by defining two operations to constructing the linear structure. But, we can define the different linear structures on a set. And I want to know that if the different linear spaces have the same dimensions? If so, what determines this?

Comment: Both $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are vector spaces over the field  $\Bbb R$ but are not of equal dimension.There is a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ so we can represent these two spaces as real vector spaces on the same set ....I could say more but right now I'm literally falling asleep.

Comment: Thanks DanielWainfleet for your so quick respond. But, I think it can not solve this problem from your idea. For your example, we can define a usual linear structure on $\mathbb{R}^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. And also we can define a usual linear structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Now, let $\phi$ is the bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$. We know it is certainly not linear. So this bijection can not transfer this linear structure back to $\mathbb{R}^1$. And you have some good approach on your idea? Could you tell me your specific way for this?  Thks!

Comment: I'm not sure what else there is to your Q. Perhaps if you were more specific....

Comment: For example $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$, we can define a usual linear structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Also we can define the following operations to construct the linear structure: $(x_1,y_1)\oplus(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2+x_1x_2), k\circ(x,y)=(kx,ky+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2)$ . It is easy to verify they have same dimensions. And I want to know whether there is a general conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  If $\ V\ $ is any set of cardinality $\ 2^{\aleph_0}\ $, then there is a bijection $\ \varphi:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\ $. Define a scalar multiplication and addition on $\ V\ $ by
$$ \lambda * v = \varphi^{-1}\left(\lambda\,\varphi\left(v\right)\right)\\
v_1 \oplus v_2 = \varphi^{-1}\left(\varphi\left(v_1\right)+\varphi\left(v_1\right)\right)\ ,$$
for $\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}, v,v_1,v_2\in V\ $.  We then have
$$ \varphi\left( \lambda * v\right)=\lambda\,\varphi\left(v\right)\ \mbox{and}\\
 \varphi\left( v_1 \oplus v_2\right)=\varphi\left(v_1\right)+\varphi\left(v_1\right)\ ,$$
so $\ \varphi\ $ is a vector space isomorphism, and $\ \left(V,*,\oplus\right)\ $ is a vector space of dimension $\ n\ $ over $\ \mathbb{R}\ $.  But we could choose $\ V\ $ to be $\ \mathbb{R}^m\ $ for any $\ m\ $.

On reviewing the comments above, I see the idea used in this answer seems to have already occurred to [DanielWainfleet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/254665/danielwainfleet).

Comment: Lonza leggiera, thanks very much for you. I understand your answer. I am very happy!

Comment: Now, I have a new problem. Since a set $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with different linear structures can have different dimensions, by what the dimension of each linear structure is determined? Whether can we know the dimension of every linear space more directly?